# How to save a row into database in ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am new to ruby on rails and I want to store data of a row in the database table. How can I do this. How do I pass data

The route:

post 'matches/:id', to: 'matches#savedata', as: 'savedata'

The erb form:

```
<%= form_with(url: savedata_path, local: true) do |f| %>
        <% @result.each do |r| %>
            <% @i = 0 %>
            <% @j = 1 %>
            <tr>
                <td><%= r[@i] %></td>
                <td><%= r[@j] %></td>
                <td><%= @match.start_date %></td>

                <td>
                    <select>
                        <option value="<% r[@i] %>" ><%= r[@i] %></option>
                        <option value="<% r[@j] %>" ><%= r[@j] %></option>
                    </select>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <%= f.submit "Save" %>
                </td>
            </tr>
        <% end %>
    <% end %>
```

The controller:

```
def savedata
    @match = Match.new(match_params)
end


private

def match_params
   params.require(:match).permit(:player_id, :tournament_id, :wins, :no_of_matches)
end
```

The migration:

```
class CreateMatches < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def change
    create_table :matches do |t|
      t.references :player
      t.references :tournament
      t.string :wins
      t.integer :no_of_matches

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Your `select` doesn't have a `name`. Actually, none of the model's fields have inputs in your form.

Comment: Sorry to be harsh here but there's just too much wrong with your code to even know where to start.  I would recommend you use the scaffold generator initially, see what it produces in a working prototype, that'll help guide you.  Also, the guides are very good: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO!

The form submit button submits the whole form, not just a single row. Having multiple submit buttons won't make a difference, each button will do the same thing.

To save just one row, you'd need to make each row its own unique form, or use AJAX, TurboFrames, or JS to send just that row data to the controller for saving.

Check out a few of these AJAX tutorials for tips and ideas:

- https://medium.com/@jelaniwoods/how-to-actually-use-ajax-in-rails-83e667ea7953
- https://www.rubyguides.com/2019/03/rails-ajax/